# iOS Swift - How to draw simple 2d Image with metal?

Tags: ios, swift, metal

In my project i need to draw 2D image in realtime corresponding with UIGestureRecognizer updates .

The image would be the same UIImage , drawing on various positions.

```
let arrayOfPositions = [pos1,pos2,pos3]
```

And i need to transfer the result image on MetalLayer into Single UIImage , the result image will have the same size as device's screen.
something similar to

```
let resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
```

I'm new to Metal and after watching realm's video and apple documentation my sanity went to chaos . Most tutorials focus on 3D rendering which is beyond my need (and my knowledge)

If anyone would help me a simple code how to draw UIImage in to MetalLayer , then convert the whole into single UIImage as a result ? thanks

Comment: Im currently using core graphic , but the result become terrible lag , core graphic seem to only capable for Path / Vector drawing .  (Its a real time-drawing app)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v10kI.jpg  https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlXz4.jpg

Comment: Have you profiled it to see why it's lagging? Core Graphics is fully intended to draw images in addition to vectors, and it does so pretty well.

Comment: problem is the draw call occurred 50times in split second, cpu went up to 94% quickly . and they failed to display underneath image . With small brush size (5 - 20 ) No lag , but with 30x30 ~ 100x100 lags alway happen.